# Drawing shapes versus rendering images?

Tags: pygame

I am using Pygame 1.9.2a with Python 2.7 for designing an experiment and have been so far using Pygame only on a need basis and am not familiar with all Pygame classes or concepts (Sprites, for instance, I have no idea about).

I am required to draw many (45 - 50 at one time) shapes on the screen at different locations to create a crowded display. The shapes vary from displaced Ts , displaced Ls to line intersections. [ Like **_|** or **†** or **‡** etc.]! I'm sorry that I am not able to post an image of this because I apparently do not have a reputation of 10, which is necessary to post images.

I also need these shapes in 8 different orientations. I was initially contemplating generating point lists and using these to draw lines. But, for a single shape, I will need four points and I need 50 of these shapes. Again, I'm not sure how to rotate these once drawn. Can I use the Pygame Transform or something? I think they can be used, say on Rects. Or will I have to generate points for the different orientations too, so that when drawn, they come out looking rotated, that is, in the desired orientation?

The alternative I was thinking of was to generate images for the shapes in GIMP or some software like that. But, for any screen, I will have to load around 50 images. Will I have to use Pygame Image and make 50 calls for something like this? Or is there an easier way to handle multiple images?

Also, which method would be a bigger hit to performance? Since, it is an experiment, I am worried about timing precision too. I don't know if there is a different way to generate shapes in Pygame. Please help me decide which of these two (or a different method) is better to use for my purposes.

Thank you!

Comment: Have one image and rotate it as necessary (by transforming it with a rotation transformation). That will be considerably more efficient than loading many images for different orientations.

Comment: Try every method on your own - this is the best method to check which one is good for you.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. @Thomas I shall try using images. The attraction I have towards generating point lists and drawing lines is that the size of my shapes is liable to change on various experimental factors. And, I thought it would be better to have variables for these and if one of them changes, I only have to change a value in my program. With images, I'll have to scale them every time. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easer to use `pygame.draw.rect()` or `pygame.draw.polygon()` (because you don't need to know how to use GIMP or InkScape :) ) but you have to draw it on another `pygame.Surface()` (to get bitmap) and than you can rotate it, add alpha (to make transparet) and than you can put it on screen.

You can create function to generate images (using Surface()) with all shapes in different orientations at program start. If you will need better looking images you can change function to load images created in GIMP.

Try every method on your own - this is the best method to check which one is good for you.

By the way: you can save generated images `pygame.image.save()` and then load it. You can have all elements on one image and use part of image `Surface.get_clip()`

Comment: Thank you! I did create an image in GIMP. But, when I tried using it, I got something like the negative of an image for rotations of 45 or 120 degrees. 90 and 270 worked fine. My images were 36 x 36 px. The monitor has a 1920 x 1200 resolution. Were they too small? Because, first I tried with images double the size and it worked fine. And, I'm not sure I can use the polygon function, but I guess I can use the rect() function. And, like you say, paint it on another surface and then make many copies of that for rotating. I'm worried though that this problem of rotation is going to stay.

Comment: Do you use `set_mode(..., 0, 32)` and `pygame.image.load(..).convert()` ?

Comment: I did try Surface.convert(), did not help. But, then, convert_alpha() solved the problem. Thank you! But, rotating using pygame.transform does not work very well for a circle. I have to enclose my shapes in circles. But, when I save the entire shape (including the circle) as an image and then rotate it, it seems to have lost some pixels. So, now, after I do the rotation on the shape, i draw the circle. If you can tell me a better way to generate circles, it'd be great. And, in terms of performance, does it make a difference if I load images or draw shapes.

Comment: And, your idea of drawing shapes with pygame and storing it as bmp worked wonderfully for me. For the size of shapes I had in mind, where, essentially each pixel mattered, it worked much better than GIMP. Thank you!

Comment: Bitmaps transforms need good algorythms to get good results. Pygame algorythms probably aren't as good as in GIMP. But vector objects give the best results - so `draw.circle()` after bitmap rotation/scaling is probably the best way to get good looking circle.

Comment: Probably you get better performace if you will not make bitmap transforms and shape draws during program. You could load images and/or draw shapes on surfaces and make transforms at program start. Than you could use bitmaps (surfaces) to blit it on screen without transforms. In many algorythms to get better time performance you have to use more memory.